# Given set M , which of following option is correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

let $M = \{ A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b\\c&d \end{bmatrix}| a,b ,c, d \in \mathbb{Z} \ \text{and the  eigenvalue  of  A  are in }\mathbb{Q}\}$ .Then

choose  the  correct option

$1.$ M is empty

$2.$$M = \{\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\c&d \end{bmatrix}| a,b ,c, d \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

$3.$if  $A \in M$ ,then  the  eigenvalue  of  $A$ are in $\mathbb{Z}$

$4.$if$ A,B \in  M$ are such that  $AB=I$ then  $det A \in \{+1,-1\}$

MY attempt :  option $1)$ is obviously false

option $2)$ is True  according to the definition of question

option $3)$  is True  take  $A=I$

option $4)$ is  True take $A= B=I$

is my attempt  is True

Any hints/solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1, you should display a matrix that is in $M$.  It should be easy to find one.

For 2, they have removed the requirement that the eigenvalues of $A$ are rational.  If you can find a matrix where the eigenvalues are not rational you show that this is not true.  Can you find one?

For 3, finding one matrix is not enough.  You are asked to show that if a matrix has integral entries and rational eigenvalues, the eigenvalues are integral.  You could think about the rational root theorem and the characteristic polynomial of matrices in $M$.

4 is the same as 3.  In fact it will follow from 3, if 3 is true.